# Can I use environment variable in the jaas.props file

Tags: jaas, jetty-9

I am using `PropertyFileLoginModule` and my `jass.conf` file looks like following

```
MyLogingModule  {
    org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    file="${jetty.home}/jass.props";

};
```

now in the `jaas.props` file I have following entry.

```
tiger: ${tiger.password},admin
```

However instead of replacing `${tiger.password}` with the actual value, it seems like it is expecting password to be exact string *${tiger.password}*

Any suggestion how to get around this issue.

Comment: any updates on this issue? where you able to provide env vars as part of jaas.conf?